# PHP Timestamp only the hour

Tags: php

I am working with timestamps to figure out if two people are online during the same time period, here are my UTC timestamps just for reference:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$utc12am = 1380585600;
$utc1am = 1380589200;
$utc2am = 1380592800;
$utc3am = 1380596400;
$utc4am = 1380600000;
$utc5am = 1380603600;
$utc6am = 1380607200;
$utc7am = 1380610800;
$utc8am = 1380614400;
$utc9am = 1380618000;
$utc10am = 1380621600;
$utc11am = 1380625200;
$utc12pm = 1380628800;
$utc1pm = 1380632400;
$utc2pm = 1380636000;
$utc3pm = 1380639600;
$utc4pm = 1380643200;
$utc5pm = 1380646800;
$utc6pm = 1380650400;
$utc7pm = 1380654000;
$utc8pm = 1380657600;
$utc9pm = 1380661200;
$utc10pm = 1380664800;
$utc11pm = 1380668400;
```

The problem I run into is if someone says they are online between 10pm and 12am that is like saying between 1380668400 and 1380585600 it's going backwards, which throws off the whole bit of code.  How would I write a timestamp that just defines the hour, not the day, or how would I work around this?  My brain is on fire.

**Update**

After much headache the answer is simpler than it needed to be, all dates are static, so grabbing them dynamically is not what I plan on doing, I am only using the date function so I don't have to write out new UTC values for every single timezone.  Anyway, I drew a picture and that really helped me out, you only need to check if $max is within the bounds of $mina - $maxa OR if $min is within the bounds of $mina - $maxa.  I can't believe this took me this long

```
    $blend = 'False';
    if((($maxa > $min) And ($maxa < $max)) Or (($mina > $min) And ($mina < $max))) {
        $blend = 'True';
    }
    if($min > $max) {
        if(($mina > $min) Or ($mina < $max)) {
            $blend = 'True';
        }
        if(($maxa > $min) Or ($maxa < $max)) {
            $blend = 'True';
        }
    }
    if($min === $max) $blend = 'True';
```

Comment: why does it matter? If you have the users' online times in UTC, then just check if they're within an hour of each other: `if(abs($user1 - $user2) <= 3600) { same time period }`./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the hour (values from 0 to 23).
15 is 3pm for example.

Comment: This gives from 12am to 10pm, not 10pm to 12am

Answer (score 1):

A timestamp stores the amount of seconds that have passed since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

This means you can get whatever you want from it (Days, Month, Hour, etc) if you just count seconds from that epoch. Php thankfully makes that easy for us.

This is the current "Hour" in 24hour format from a timestamp.

`$hour = date("G", 1380621600);`

This means that all timestamps from 1380621600 to 1380621600+3599 will return 10 (am) and that should be what you are looking for.

If you want to find out if someone was online between 10 and 12 am then you just check if `date("G",<timestamp>)` is between 10 and 12.

If you want to check if someone was online on October 1st, 2013 between 10 and 12 then you can use the previous method in addition with some extra arguments to get exactly what you want:

```
$year = date("Y", <timestamp>);  
$month = date("F", <timestamp>);  
$date = date("j", <timestamp>);
```

You can also do this in one step using explode if you are feeling adventurous.

`$logged_in = date("Y F j G", <timestamp>)`

If you want to see if two users are online during the same time then you can just sort everyones 'online hours' and run one linear scan through the list (using the hours that we can now figure out) to figure out overlaps.

---

References:

[PHP - Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
[PHP - Explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Hello there, although this is correct this is not what I'm looking for.  In your example all that changes when someone is searching from 9pm to 2am the values are now 21 - 2, which is still negative

Comment: I never told you to subtract hours. But its trivial to only subtract if the first hour is less then the second hour otherwise add 24 to the second hour and then subtract. Also I don't know why you are subtracting anything at all.  You said you wanted to know if people are online during the same hours, figuring how long they are online I have explained above.

Comment: It seems that your question asks for something else than what you are looking for. Many people have helped you figure out how to get the hour from the timestamp as per your heading and I've told you that you need a linear scan through the time everyone has set as their online time to figure out if they are online during the same time period. You, for some reason, are subtracting hours in everyones answer (incorrectly by the way) and then telling them that you want somethign else. Make up your mind, and write proper questions. I cant read minds.

Comment: Also, mark someones answer as correct based on the question you asked. Not based on the question that you actually wanted to ask but didn't.

Comment: I think you simply don't understand, I am saying 21 to 2, not 21 minus 2, why you think I would subtract in this instance I have no idea.  You can read what I added on to my question for what I was looking for, how about you go be butt-hurt somewhere else the flame was unnecessary.

Comment: If you mean "to" then HOW would anything ever be negative? Clearly some (incorrect) substraction going on which is what I was pointing out. Unless of course you are using the negative numbers to mean something else in your bode but it didn't seem like it from what you were saying. Obviously for 2100hours to 0200hours you would do 26-21 to figure out how many hours. If you are doing it correctly, then great! I have no issue. But I am simply confused as to how you are getting negative numbers.